# MS Graph Events API returns empty list when querying a room

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft365

I am using MS Graph API to retrieve events from users' and rooms' calendars. For one of our customers I receive an empty list when I am trying to grab events for a room resource. This is weird because in the holder calendar i can clearly see that there is an event which has this room as an attendee. The only noticable thing is that the status is `none`, not sure if that can be related.

```
            "attendees": [
                {
                    "type": "resource",
                    "status": {
                        "response": "none",
                        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                    },
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "name": "Meeting Room 2",
                        "address": "MeetingRoom2@test.com"
                    }
                }
            ],
```

Anyways, if i then call the `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/MeetingRoom2@test.com/events` i receive an empty list of events (yes, the responce is 200, no errors, just the empty array). Any ideas what could cause this? Perhaps some config setting on the customer's side?